# execute ajax before the action in a form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I hope you can help me

I have this form

```
<form action="do_login.php?id=" method=post>
    <label>Enter your Frequent Diner ID</label><br>
    <div class="shake-id">
    <input id="fd-id" class="log-input" type="text" name=loginid value="" maxlength="8" placeholder="Frequent Diner ID" /><br>
    </div>
    <div class="id-alert" style="display: none;">Your Frequent Diner ID must have 8 digits. Check and try again</div>
    <label>Enter your Password</label><br>
    <div class="shake-pass">
        <input id="pass" class="log-input" type="password" name=password value="" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" /><br>
    </div>
    <div class="pass-alert" style="display: none;">Pass wrong</div>
    <input type=hidden name=call_from value="login.php">
    <input type=hidden name=forward_url value="<?PHP echo urlencode(@$_REQUEST["forward_url"])?>"><br><br>
    <input id="test" type=submit value="Login">
</form>
```

This form execute the file do_login.php (I can not modify this action) but I have added this script before to execute the form:

```
$('form').submit(function () {

    var value = document.getElementById('fd-id').value;

    if (value.length !== 8) {
        $('.shake-id').effect("shake");
        $('.id-alert').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#fd-id').addClass('input-wrong');
        return false;
    }

    var value1 = $("#fd-id").val();
    var value2 = $("#pass").val();

    $.ajaxSetup({url: "check.php",type: 'POST', async: true, data: 'parametro1='+value1+'&parametro2='+value2+'', 
        success: function(result){

            if (result==("OK")){
                return true; //here should execute DO_LOGIN.PHP
            } else {
                $('.shake-pass').effect("shake");
                $('.pass-alert').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#pass').addClass('input-wrong');
                return false; //here should NOT execute the DO_LOGIN.PHP
            } 

        },
        error:function(){
           alert('dio error');
        } 
    });
    $.ajax();

});
```

This is working properly but the form is still calling to do_login.php. I want to call the form only if the ajax is successfull... I have added `return false;` and `return true;` in the ajax but anyway after process keep executing do_login.php

If you see my first lines of the script them execute another verification and return the form false successful but when I use the same in the ajax the return false looks like it doesnt work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the ajax request is asynchronous. So the form submitwon't wait for the ajax request to complete and return true/false, since the default action is not prevented the form is submitted.

The solution is to prevent the form submit in the submit handler, then in the ajax handler if the request is successfull then call the submit again.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    //stop form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    var value = document.getElementById('fd-id').value;

    if (value.length !== 8) {
        $('.shake-id').effect("shake");
        $('.id-alert').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#fd-id').addClass('input-wrong');
        return false;
    }

    var value1 = $("#fd-id").val();
    var value2 = $("#pass").val();

    var frm = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'parametro1=' + value1 + '&parametro2=' + value2 + '',
        success: function (result) {

            if (result == ("OK")) {
                frm.submit();
            } else {
                $('.shake-pass').effect("shake");
                $('.pass-alert').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#pass').addClass('input-wrong');
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('dio error');
        }
    });

});
```

Also note that I have removed the use of `ajasSetup` as it is not really needed, just use `$.ajax()` directly

Comment: And if you decide to call do_login.php with normal behaviour after the custom submit (for whatever reason), you can propagate the event at the end of the submit function.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault();

Place this just after you form submit function.